# gdb: info locals on a selected frame

Tags: c++, c, gdb

Just a simple ask:

The `(gdb) info locals` command gives the list of local variables and their values.

Are these values initialized values or point in time of execution of that frame?
Can you provide any documentation around this?

Comment: Why can't you try it yourself with a simple test program?

Comment: Whenever you print the value of a variable, it's the *current* value of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these values initialized values or point in time of execution of that frame?

The latter. [Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Frame-Info.html) says:

"These are all variables (declared either static or automatic) accessible
at the **point of execution** of the selected frame."